# python - remove dictionary from list if exists

Tags: python

I am trying to remove a dictionary from a list if it already exists but it doesn't seem to be working.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong or advise me what I should be doing

```
new_dict = {'value': 'some value', 'key': 'someKey'}
if new_dict in my_list:
    my_list.remove(new_dict)
```

new_list is a list of dictionaries where new_dict is definitely in

Comment: This works for me. How do you build my_list ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `new_dict` is "definitely" in `my_list`, then `my_list.remove(new_dict)` should do the trick (i.e., no need for the `if new_dict in my_list`, that just slows it down).

Comment: This. To be on the safe side, you could wrap that in a `try/except` and deal with `ValueError`s then.

Answer (score 4):

```
my_list = [1,{'value':'some value', 'key' :'somekey'}, 2, {'z':'z', 'x': 'x'}]
new_dict = {'value':'some value', 'key' :'somekey'}
#new_dict = {'z':'z', 'x': 'x'}

differ = 0
matched = 0
for element in my_list:
    if type(element) is types.DictType and matched != 0:
        differ = 0
        # check if dictionary keys match
        if element.viewkeys() == new_dict.viewkeys():
            # check if dictionary values match
            for key in element.keys():
                if element[key] != new_dict[key]:
                    differ = 1
        matched = 1

if differ != 1:
    my_list.remove(new_dict)

print my_list
```

It worked for both of the dictionaries for me.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases it is clever to build a new list:

```
 new_list = [ dd for dd in my_list if not dd is new_dict ]
```

This is typical for a functional programming style, as it avoids side effects. Imagine if you use your solution in a function or method. In most cases you need a modified list only for internal purposes, then modifying an input parameter is dangerous.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `is` here instead of `==`?

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. It's another way which will not change anything if what he's got isn't working for him. And personally, I disagree strongly with you that "in most cases it is clever to build a new list". I would say that occasionally it will be desired, but almost always it will just be inefficient.

Comment: @Tim: That depends. But as the question used "in", you are right, it should be "==".

Comment: @Chris: Ok, that should have been a comment, not an answer. I did not say that functional programming style gives you the most effecitive code. But I prefer this style unless I get performance problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may come from the fact that removing from a list while iterating over the *same* list is not safe. What you want to do is something like:

```
copied_list = my_list[:]
if new_dict in copied_list:
    my_list.remove(new_dict)
```

This way, you iterate over a copy of the list and remove from the original.

This may not be the cause of your problem though. It would be interesting to see:

- how you build `my_list`
- what you do with `my_list` after the loop, i.e. how do you realise your dictionary was not removed